# How to export something from another file in flow?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

Let's say I have a module like this:

- module

  - index.js
  - a.js

and now I want to export a in my index.js file.
In es6 this would look like this:

```
export a from "./a"
```

But flow gives me an error:
Unknown identifier

for the a

How would I do this in flow?

Comment: you can try `module.exports = require('./a')`

Comment: I just realized that I can do import a from "./a"; export { a }.
But still this feels redundant

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is a [Stage 1 proposal](https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from), and [Flow currently doesn't support it](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/940).

As you mentioned in your comment, you have to do separate import & exports for now.

Comment: You can do `export {default as a} from "./a"` too.